# Add upperCase method in player.ts

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular. 
I create new project in-memory-web-api, all worked but i must add method in player.ts who upperCase me player object in app.component.ts

the player is a object and i must generate upperCase method in player.ts who upperCase me player object in app.component.ts

How i can do this?

Now i have upperCase method in app.component.ts and working but how i can create method upperCase in player.ts ?

My project:

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlayerService } from './player.service';
import { PlayerNationality } from './player';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private playerService: PlayerService) {}

  players: PlayerNationality[];
  formPlayer: PlayerNationality;
  showForm: boolean;
  newForm: boolean;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPlayers();
  }

  getPlayers(): void {
    this.playerService.getPlayer().subscribe(players => this.players = players);
  }

  addOrUpdatePlayer(player: PlayerNationality) {
    if(this.newForm) {
      this.playerService.addPlayer(player).subscribe(add => this.players.push(add));
    }
    else {
      this.playerService.updatePlayer(player).subscribe(() => {});
    }
    this.newForm = false;
    this.hidePlayerForm();
  }

  deletePlayer(player: PlayerNationality) {
    this.playerService.deletePlayer(player).subscribe(() => this.deletePlayerFromList(player));
  }

  deletePlayerFromList(player: PlayerNationality) {
    const index = this.players.indexOf(player, 0)
    if(index > -1) {
      this.players.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }

  upperCase(player: PlayerNationality) {
    player.name = player.name.toUpperCase();
    player.last = player.last.toUpperCase();
    player.nationality = player.nationality.toUpperCase();
    console.log(player);
  }

  playerChange(player) {
    player.name = player.last;
    player.last = player.nationality;
  }

  showPlayerForm(player: PlayerNationality) {
    if(!player) {
      player = new PlayerNationality()
      this.showForm = true;
      this.newForm = true;
    }
    this.showForm = true;
    this.formPlayer = player;
  }

  hidePlayerForm() {
    this.showForm = false;
  }
}
```

player.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { PlayerNationality } from './player';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { PlayerNationalityData } from './player-data';

@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  private url = 'app/players';
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

  getPlayer(): Observable<PlayerNationality[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(response => response.json());
  }

  addPlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<PlayerNationality> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, player, this.options).map(response => response.json());
  }

  updatePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
    const updateUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`
    return this.http.put(updateUrl, player, this.options).map(response => response.json());
  }

  deletePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
    const deleteUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`
    return this.http.delete(deleteUrl).map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

player.ts:

```
import { PlayerService } from './player.service';

export class PlayerNationality {
    id: number;
    name: String;
    last: String;
    nationality: String;
}
```

player-data.ts:

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class PlayerNationalityData implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        const players = [
            {id: 1, name: 'Joseph', last: 'Dart', nationality: 'Scotland'},
            {id: 2, name: 'Joseph', last: 'Dart', nationality: 'Scotland'},
            {id: 3, name: 'Joseph', last: 'Dart', nationality: 'Scotland'}
        ];

        return {players};
    }
}
```

Comment: now i have upperCase method in app.component.ts and working but how i can create method upperCase in player.ts ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite understand your question. But you are doing it wrong,,,
But if you want to have upperCase method in player.ts

```
             //import { PlayerService } from './player.service'; //remove this line.. you don't need this import of a service class since this is a model class

                export class PlayerNationality {
                    public id: number;
                    public name: String;
                    public last: String;
                    public nationality: String;

//note this method will change the case to uppercase of "name", "last","nationality" 

                toUpperCase(){
                   this.name=this.name.toUpperCase();
                   this.last=this.last.toUpperCase(); 
                   this.nationality=this.nationality.toUpperCase();
                }       
            }
```

Now you can call this method from anywhere if you have the *PlayerNationality* object

PlayerService.ts

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { PlayerNationality } from './player';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { PlayerNationalityData } from './player-data';

    @Injectable()
    export class PlayerService {

      constructor(private http: Http) {}

      private url = 'app/players';
      private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
      private options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });

      getPlayer(): Observable<PlayerNationality[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(response => response.json());
      }

      addPlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<PlayerNationality> {
        return this.http.post(this.url, player, this.options).map(response => response.json());
      }

      updatePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
        const updateUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`

        //suppose you want to have playerNationality to uppercase here...

        player.toUpperCase(); //add line
        return this.http.put(updateUrl, player, this.options).map(response => response.json());
      }

      deletePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
        const deleteUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`
        return this.http.delete(deleteUrl).map(response => response.json());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Dont working :/  i need upperCase my player object by method in player.ts when i click a button. So i must use upperCase method in app.component but method must be created at player.ts

Answer (score 0):

Since `PlayerNationality` is a class itself, it can have some methods.

Also, why do you `import { PlayerService } from './player.service';` in `player.ts`. Seems unnecessary to me.

```
export class PlayerNationality {
    // if your constructor has some inputs with `public`, `protected` or `private`, 
    // typescript will create those field for you in your class.
    constructor(
        public id: number,
        public name: string,
        public last: string,
        public nationality: string) {
        this.upperCase(); // call upperCase to make everything upper case
    }

    upperCase() {
        this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
        this.last = this.last.toUpperCase();
        this.nationality = this.nationality.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

in `player-data.ts`

```
export class PlayerNationalityData implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        const players: PlayerNationality[] = [
            new PlayerNationality(1, 'Joseph', 'Dart', 'Scotland'),
            new PlayerNationality(2, 'Joseph', 'Dart', 'Scotland'),
            new PlayerNationality(3, 'Joseph', 'Dart', 'Scotland')
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Now i have                                                                                                 [ts]Type '{ id: number; name: string; last: string; nationality: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'PlayerNationality[]'.
  Type '{ id: number; name: string; last: string; nationality: string; }' is not assignable to type 'PlayerNationality'.
    Property 'upperCase' is missing in type '{ id: number; name: string; last: string; nationality: string; }'.
const players: PlayerNationality[]

Comment: You have to use the constructor, you can't just use a json any more.

Comment: Yea i know but the error is in the player-data.ts 'player: PlayerNationality[] = [] get this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the response json from the server a type of `PlayerNationality` and not just an object.

I am a fan of having a constructor for my transfer objects that take a partial of that object and then set the appropriate properties. Example:

```js
export class PlayerNationality {
    id: number;
    name: String;
    last: String;
    nationality: String;

    constructor(player: Partial<PlayerNationality>) {
        Object.entries(player).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if(!(this[key] instanceof Function)) {
                this[key] = value;
            }
        });
    }

    public upperCase(){
        this.name = this.name.toUpperCase();
        this.last = this.last.toUpperCase();
        this.nationality = this.nationality.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class PlayerService {

  getPlayer(): Observable<PlayerNationality[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(response => response.json().map((p) => new PlayerNationality(p)));
  }

  addPlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<PlayerNationality> {
    return this.http.post(this.url, player, this.options).map(response => new PlayerNationality(response.json()));
  }

  updatePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
    const updateUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`
    return this.http.put(updateUrl, player, this.options).map(response => new PlayerNationality(response.json()));
  }

  deletePlayer(player: PlayerNationality): Observable<any> {
    const deleteUrl = `${this.url}/${player.id}`
    return this.http.delete(deleteUrl).map(response => new PlayerNationality(response.json()));
  }
}
```

Comment: Working, but im a new in angular. I dont understand this. Can help me in an easier way ?

Comment: No, this the correct way to do this. You could also get access to the method by not adding a constructor and doing `const player = { ...new PlayerNationality(), ...jsonPerson }` but, in my opinion, this is not as clear.

Comment: Thanks, i think i must spend a lot of time with angular to be good :) thanks for give me correct way.

Comment: Now i have problem with app.component.ts in showPlayerForm method i have player = new PlayerNationality() and have error.

Comment: That is because the constructor for `PlayerNationality` takes an argument and you are not passing it one. If you want to instantiate `PlayerNationality` without any arguments change the constructor definition to `constructor(player?: Partial<PlayerNationality>)` and wrap the body of the constructor in an `if` so the code only runs if `player` is defined.